# Help understanding how avrdude works with ArduinoISP and why its not working for me

Tags: avr, avrdude, isp, atmega2560, arduinoisp

I am trying to use avrdude with a Mega2560 running ArduinoISP

Note: I have the 10uF cap on the Mega2560 RESET line as described by Ardunio.

Also, I am using avrdude/6.3 on Windows 10.  The Mega2560(ArduinoISP) is connected to the PC using an a USB cable - connection is COM8.

I have a couple of tasks I want to do

1. Update the firmware on my USBASP
2. Load Arduino boot on ATTINY85 dev board.

I started with Arduino IDE but moved to avrdude to better understand the problem

For #1:
Wired it per https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/ArduinoISP

```
AVR-ISP pin     MEGA-ISP pin
6/10 (name)

1/9 (MISO)      50  
2/2 (VCC)       VCC
3/7 (SCK)       52
4/1 (MOSI)      51
5/5 (RESET)     53
6/10 (GND)      GND
```

I tried using the command:

```
avrdude -c arduino -p m8 -P COM8
```

I get the error

```
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 1 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xed
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 2 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xe0
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 3 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xe0
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 4 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xe0
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 5 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 6 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xe0
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 7 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xe0
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 8 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xe0
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 9 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 10 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xe0

avrdude done.  Thank you.
```

--UPDATE-- The error above was caused by not setting the BAUD rate. Now I get:

```
avrdude: Device signature = 0x000000
avrdude: Yikes!  Invalid device signature.
```

What I really want to know is more of how this process works so I can better understand it and be able to debug the issues.

1. Is this an error communicating with the ISP (Arduino) or is it an issue with the ISP talking to the target (ATMega8B on USBAVR)?
2. What does "stk500" mean?  Is that the programming protocol, the ISP protocol, or something all together different?
3. Is this all documented somewhere?

Comment: baud rate, fuses? use IDE to burn the botloader

Comment: I get similar errors when I try to use the IDE (which I believe uses avrdude in the bacground.  That is why I am focused on understanding avrdude.  Note: I normally use the IDE but not with a ISP.

Comment: Please add info about the wiring.

Comment: Added wiring info

Comment: 1. `programmer is not responding` seems to show the problem is with the programmer, not the target. 2. stk500 is the protocol the Arduino uses to program itself. I don't think this should be the protocol to use when using the Arduino-as-ISP, but it's been a while. 3. Not really. All the info is out there, but not in one place.

Comment: I think `-c arduino` should be `-c avrisp -b 19200`

Comment: @Gerben baud rate appear to have been what was causing the 'not responding'.  It now responds but I get 'Invalid device signature'.

Comment: What signature do you get?

Comment: the command for Uno as target and "Arduino as ISP" is `avrdude -C avrdude.conf -v -patmega328p -cstk500v1 -P/dev/ttyACM0 -b19200 -e -Ulock:w:0x3F:m -Uefuse:w:0xFD:m -Uhfuse:w:0xDE:m -Ulfuse:w:0xFF:m` as you can see in IDE console when you use "Burn bootloader"

Comment: @Juraj That is pretty much the same as what I am using but 1)my target is different, and I am no writing of fuses and  lock

Comment: @Gerben 'avrdude: Device signature = 0x000000'

Comment: @MikaelPatel I added detail on the wiring to the OP

Comment: @Gerben Re:`Not really. All the info is out there, but not in one place`  I am finding some stuff and collecting it and will add it as a Answer so it can at least be in this _one place_.

Comment: the Arduino as ISP page doesn't show wiring for USBASP or ATiny

Comment: @Juraj Arduino ISP page shows the pin numbers on each ISP board type by AVR-ISP signal name.  I just connect those to the same signal name on the target (USPASP/ATTINY).  For one example (USPASP) I added the specific connections.

Comment: `Device signature = 0x000000'` means it can't see/communicate with the target.

Comment: You have the use the correct reset pin on the USBasp. You can't use the 'reset' pin on the programming header on the USBasp, as that's is just a GPIO output pin on the ATMega8. It seems that some of the board have a jumper to connect this pin to the reset on the ATMeag8. Not properly resetting the target could give you the incorrect signature error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The target board was not reset.

The "Arduino as ISP" sketch uses pin 10 to reset the target, not the SS pin. So even on Mega, wire reset of target to pin 10, not to pin 53.
[image]

> Is this an error communicating with the ISP (Arduino) or is it an issue with the ISP talking to the target (ATMega8B on USBAVR)?

the first error "not in sync" is a problem with communication with the programmer. it was caused by wrong baud rate. the "invalid signature" is a response from the programmer about target. if the signature could be read avrdude would print the target MCU type. all zeros signature is when the target doesn't answer. so check the wiring.

> What does "stk500" mean? Is that the programming protocol, the ISP protocol, or something all together different?

yes it is a ISP programming protocol. the "Arduino as ISP" implements only this protocol

> Is this all documented somewhere?

this is AVR MCU world, not Arduino. you can google avrdude reference, stk500 reference etc

Comment: This got it working.  How did you know it was the reset?

Comment: I use "Arduino as ISP" quite often. You could accept the answer to mark the question solved

Comment: Just recall that the question was not just to solve the immediate issue; but, to know how to trace the symptoms to the cause.  If you can add how the symptoms pointed you to the RESET connection then that would be a more complete answer.  Also I need to test it with the other test case.

Comment: the "check the wiring" rule. I enhanced the answer